# Chart tooltip should show the consolidated information of a single bar in double bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[chart.js][1]

Please find the link of the required chart tooltip image

https://ibb.co/4t7KJmS

Here is the code I am using for tooltip

```
tooltips: {
mode: 'index',
intersect: true,
itemSort: function(a, b) {
    return b.datasetIndex - a.datasetIndex
},
filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
    var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
    if (value === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, }
```

I have a chart whith month as X axis and Amount as Y axis. For every month there are two bars - one for monthly amount for every entity and other for historical avg amount of the entities. I am getting a combined tooltip for a month which has details of monthly and avg activity when I am hovering on any of the bar for that month. I want a consolidated tooltip for a single bar of a month.

For example : August month have two bars - one for monthly amount and other for historical avg amount then when I hover on Monthly bar it should show me the consolidated tooltip of monthly activity for August and when I hover the Avg bar then it should show me the consolidated tooltip of avg amount.

Use below link to get the better idea of the requirement from the image

https://ibb.co/4t7KJmS

Comment: This is resolved by using below tootlip option

mode: 'index',
mode: 'x',

Answer (score 0):

Changing `mode: 'index'` to `mode: 'point'` will fix your issue

Comment: If i change the mode to 'point' then it shows the tooltip information for every stack in the bar but it does not show the consolidated tooltip information. Can please refer to the image for which I have provided the link.